# No notification sent when a row is deleted from a view-based table view

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode5, nstableview

I'm using Xcode 5 working on a simple core data app with a table view and buttons to add/delete rows. I started with a **cell-based** table view. The view delegate receives the tableViewSelectionDidChange notification so that the delete button can be disabled if no row is selected:

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // enable/disable removeButton according to rows selected
    [removeButton setEnabled:([tableView numberOfSelectedRows] ? YES : NO)];
    NSLog(@"numberOfSelectedRows: %li", [tableView numberOfSelectedRows]);
}
```

This works as expected.

I then changed the table view to **view-based** mode to add more data cells to the row. And here's the problem. I click on a row to select it - the delete button is enabled. Click the button - the row is deleted, but no notification is sent, so the button is still enabled, even though no row is highlighted. Interestingly when I click delete again another row is deleted! I'm stumped here. There's no mention of this issue on SO, google didn't help either.

Any ideas? You can download the two versions here: [bitpals.de/cloudlock.zip](http://bitpals.de/cloudlock.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All is well now; after hours of tenacious googling I found the solution.

It seems that an obscure binding is needed to keep the table view selection in sync with the array controller.

The table view's `Selection Indexes` must be bound to the array controllers `selectionIndexes`:

[image]

See [View based NSTableView and NSArrayController not in sync](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/309747-view-based-nstableview-and-nsarraycontroller-not-in-sync.html) over on cocoabuilder.com.